# Starting android service with two ways

Tags: android, service

I have a batch of data to load from web. But I need to initiate loading in two ways:
1) Every N minuts
2) Immediately loading by click refresh button

Which is best way to implement this issue? Should I create two services: firs for looping datat loading and second for single loading, or i can combine this functionality into one service or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single function that loads the data from the web and then write a method that calls that function after a specified time ,and also call the same function on refresh button click event.